# How to deal with a user who keeps asking the same question over and over?

Tags: discussion, tag-abuse

There's [a new user on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444039/ruhi) who keeps asking more or less the same exact question about Drupal user permissions:

- [How to give access to users at page level in drupal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682465/how-to-give-access-to-users-at-page-level-in-drupal)
- [page created to be editable only by user owning that page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714886/page-created-to-be-editable-only-by-user-owning-that-page)
- [How can I make a user's content private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732791/how-can-i-make-a-users-content-private)
- [Private module not making content private in Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733093/private-module-not-making-content-private-in-drupal)
- [How do I assign users to a particular group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724002/how-do-i-assign-users-to-a-particular-group)

All of the questions are of pretty low quality, so it's not surprising he's not getting answers. Voting to close them as duplicates is the standard procedure, but is there any additional steps (like flagging to a moderator) one should take for users who don't seem to *get it*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These "how do I set permissions in drupal" questions are not *programming* questions. Therefore I have closed them all.

Comment: I agree these questions are low quality and borderline abusive, but what ever happened to allowing questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers"? I think CMS certainly applies.

Comment: @jonb I don't see anything programmery about "how do I set user permissions via the web interface in drupal". Drupal is not a programmer's tool. Now if it was about how to modify the PHP code underneath..

Comment: @Jeff - I don't use Drupal, but I use another CMS to run my company's website. And I'm a programmer. One minute I'm writing ASP.NET code, the next I'm tweaking something in the CMS via its web UI to make my pages work right. I'm not defending this user, but I'd hate to ask a CMS question on SO and have it closed as off-topic.

Comment: @jonb belongs on webmaster.se in that case. How to click buttons and make selections in a web UI for a CMS simply isn't *programming*.

Comment: How do I add an XML file to my project in VS2010? Is that programming?

Comment: How do I create a new repository in SVN?

Comment: How do I see differences between two versions of a source file?

Comment: The questions were so low quality it was difficult to tell whether they were just webmaster questions (because the solution already existed) or required providing explanations of Drupal's access API (because he needed to create a custom module). I don't think there was any great loss in closing them: they weren't going to help anyone anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Don't worry, if this continues he will soon receive the

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

I'll quote [Jeff's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294):

> Based on the feedback from this post, we have now implemented a form of screening during the question ask period.
>
> Questions from IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor questions will no longer be accepted. This is intended to weed out the worst quality questions.
>
> (hint hint, question votes matter, so please continue to vote the best questions up and vote the worst questions down.)
>
> Based on our queries and a random audit sample of affected accounts / IP addresses, it seems effective, but we'll have to see now that it's deployed and perhaps tweak further.
>
> Note, the /ask page error text is of the form:
> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

Comment: Aha, I'm sure he'll trigger it soon enough. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I'm not sure where the threshold is, but there are not many people looking at Drupal questions that can vote to close and the amount of downvotes is also generally small. Let's see if he manages to trigger it.

Answer (score 3):

If closing the question, downvoting and comments have failed, I think we need to leave it to the moderating team.

And accept that some people just don't get it even if you hit them with a 16-ton cluebat. Just price yourself lucky that you are not that clueless.

Answer (score 3):

If down-votes don't seem to be getting through then you should certainly comment, but in a positive way - suggesting improvements or pointing the OP here for example.

However, flagging is *always* an option & while moderators may complain about the work load it's usually tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: Yeah, comments don't seem to be working. I've flagged it, but the automated system [Tobias mentioned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64815/how-to-deal-with-a-user-who-keeps-asking-the-same-question-over-and-over/64820#64820) will likely kick in.